# How Do I install DB2 Remotely?

Tags: aix, putty, xming, db2

I have been trying to install IBM DB2 10.5.0.1 on AIX 7.1.0.0 from a Windows 8-64bit using a Remote connection. It has been 3 days and I haven't been able to succeed; Here is a list of everything I've done so far:

1. I have installed Putty on my Local Machine ( win-8, 64 bit)
2. I have installed Xming
3. I even installed Cygwin

---

I keep receiving the following error message after several unsuccessful trys to install the DB on the remote machine:

> (The Tools) command-line, telnet, and relogin client have stopped
>   working.

**Additional Information**:

The Database file is zipped using tar format and I have already untarred it, and I want to attempt an install using the db2setup command, which as far as I understand starts the Installer Wizard.

**Connection Setup**

I disabled my firewall, and am only connected to the remote AIX Server through my LAN.  My LAN is also not connected to the internet.

---

I tried to run the following commands:

xclock and  Xming separately from the command line of Putty and Cygwin. The result was an error.

I also tried to export the display with the command :

```
DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0; export DISPLAY

DISPLAY=datapc:0.0; export DISPLAY

DISPLAY=localhost:0.0; export DISPLAY
```

After I tried once and the installation failed, I kept trying while adding new troubleshooting, and kept failing.

I am ready to start with a clean slate, so instead of trying to repair what I've done already, I'm looking for help from all of you regarding the BEST method.  Id appreciate that!!

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

**@ Archemar** : Since the ultimate goal was to install DB2 on remote AIX server, I was hoping that if my method was wrong, someone would show me a way other than X11, so the title is correct.

Here is how I solved the problem:

1. I went to the place where **Xming** was installed, i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming` in my case
2. I edited the `X0.hosts` file. It originally contains only `<Localhost>` then I append in the next line the IP address of my AIX server, e.g. 192.168.100.100. You can add as many server IP addresses as you need. NB: Saving it might be a little tricky, so you might need to copy it to your desktop, edit it, save it and replace it with the original file.
3. **Right click** on the Xming and click on **Properties**, then in the **Target** text box, you will see a bunch of texts; **go to the end** of the line and **add a single blank space** and the (`-ac`) characters without the parenthesis.
4. Click **Ok**.

Now you can try to `xclock` it after you export the display.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux. Good job finding an answer to your question and posting it here. You also post here a comment to @Archemar. It'd be better to post that comment directly to Archemar's answer so that he can be notified of it and it's clear to everyone what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

when you run xming, you have to specify

- a local display number e.g. 1234 (first screen)
- no access control (before last screen)

when you run putty

- in connexion -> ssh -> X11,

  - enable X11 forawding
  - set X display location to localhost:1234.0

(this tell putty to forward X11 to Xming)

It is best not to set DISPLAY.

By the way, this looks rather an X11 question rather than a database question, you should edit question title.

Answer (score 0):

After rereading and editing your post, I believe you are confusing your Local Machine with your Remote Connection.  XMing does not install an XServer on AIX as AIX has it's own XServer.  The Instructions below will give you a command line interface that will work, but you'll get no wizard.

1. Remove Putty
2. Remove Xming
3. Remove Cygwin
4. Install Cygwin
5. Use SSH while in Cygwin to login to AIX as a user with root permisions
6. Attempt [these directions](http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/db2-udb-v9/how-to-install-db2-v9-5-in-aix).  These should work regardless of version.

If you want to use the wizard, follow these steps:

1. Remove Putty
2. Remove XMing
3. Remove Cygwin
4. Install Cygwin
5. Install [XOrg using Cygwin](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup-cygwin-x-installing.html).  See Step 15.
6. Install a Desktop Environment in Cygwin, so you will have access to a remote desktop protocol program.
7. Use the RDP program to connect to the AIX Server.  If the AIX Server has an X Server this will start it.
8. Run the `db2setup` program.